# how to separate a number from a string

Tags: c, string

Actually I need to handle situation like

I should be giving input as `rows <n>`
There should be space between 'rows' and number `<n>` or any single non numeric character.

I should be able to separate that string part and assign it to a char variable and number part to a int...

The string part should be then verified whether its a correct command or not.. If a wrong command is entered like "ada aad 99" or "adaha 9" or "adfad9".. It should say "its wrong command".

I tried to use `strtok()`, but it can't handle strings where there isn't `NULL` in between strings.. I tried to use $ `sscanf(string,"%s %*c %d",str, &num);` 
but its even not working for all possibilities.

How can I do it?

Comment: Your profile says crazy about programming but You are being lazy about it in practice.Basically,You are just asking us to write a program for you.Well,if there are'nt any in-built functions that can do the job for you,why don't you try to write your own code for it?

Comment: Well, the answer is "find the space". Once you have found the space, you know that the word  should be to the left of it, and the number to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see your problem with `strtok`, it would be perfect in this case I think.

In pseudo-code:

```
line = getline();
split_line_into_tokens(line);
if tokens[0] == "command1" {
    if tokens_num > 2 {
        error("to many arguments to command1");
    } else if tokens_num < 2 {
        error("command1 needs one argument");
    } else {
        do_command_1(tokens[1]);
    }
} else {
    error("unknown command");
}
```

In the above pseudo-code, `split_line_into_tokens()` uses `strtok` to create an array of *tokens*, using space as the separator. If `strtok` returns an empty string (not `NULL`) then there is more than one space used and you skip that. The `split_line_into_tokens` creates the `tokens` array, which first entry contains the command, and the remaining contains the arguments. The variable `tokens_num` is set to the number of tokens in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think `strtok()` is exactly what you need here. If your program is multithreaded you may want to use `strtok_r()`. Once you isolate the second token you need to use `atoi()` or `strtol()` (or one of the similar functions) to parse it as a number.