# char into int and calculate sum of int

Tags: c

I want split the following string into alphabet and numbers, then I need to calculate the sum of the numbers. My sample question is `a[20]={"abcd123dc2"};`

Expected output:

```
abcddc 8
```

My code:

```
int main()
{
    char a[20] = {"abcd123dc2"};
    int l = 0, m = 0, n = 0, j, cc = 0, ll = 0;
    char b[20];
    char c[10];
    l = strlen(a);
    printf("%d", l);
    for (j = 0; j < l; j++)
    {
        if (a[j] == 'a' || a[j] == 'b' || a[j] == 'd' || a[j] == 'c')
        {
            b[m] = a[j];
            m++;
        }
    }
    b[m] = '\0';
    for (j = 0; j < l; j++)
    {
        if (a[j] == '3' || a[j] == '2' || a[j] == '1')
        {
            c[n] = a[j];
            n++;
        }
    }
    ll = strlen(c);
    atoi(c);
    for (j = 0; j < ll; j++)
    {
        cc += c[j];
    }
    printf("%d\n\n", cc);
    printf("%s", b);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: here there are a couple of hints, it's basically everything you need to know if you read carefully and think about the core of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020376/how-to-separate-a-number-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

```
char a[20]={"abd123vf"};
int l=0,m=0,j,cc=0;
char b[20];
l=strlen(a);

for(j=0;j<l;j++)
{
 if(a[j]> 47 && a[j] <58){
 cc+ = a[j] - '0';
}
 else{
  b[m]=a[j];
  m++;
 }
}
b[m]='\0';

printf("%d\n\n",cc);
printf("%s",b);
getch();
return 0;
```

Edit after the first comment:

Since you have not specifically mentioned a problem, I assume you are looking for a better way of writing this code.

Instead of looping through your string twice, you can do it in a single go.
Instead of checking for individual numbers or letters, you can check if the character is in the range : 48 - 57 [i.e., 0 to 9]

Instead of two if conditions, you can go for an else.
[Note that even the special characters in the original string will be part of your new string in this case]

`a[j] - '0'` will give the actual number in the string. eg:
if the number is 5, a[j] will be 53;
'0' is 48; 53 - 48 = 5 and that's what you add to your sum

Comment: It's better that you explain *why* your code solves the problem. Check [answer].

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo . I'll do that. I was thinking that what I did there was kinda self-explanatory.  Thinking of it again, if it were, the correction itself would not be necessary in the first place.

Comment: Even documenting the code adds value for people who want to understand. A code dump only help copy pasta programmers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK for the most part.

There is one error in computing `c`. Instead of

```
    cc += c[j]; // The integer value of c[j] when it is `0` is 48, not 0
```

You need to use

```
    cc += c[j] - '0';
```

Based on your expected output at the top of the question, your `printf` lines

```
printf("%d\n\n",cc);
printf("%s",b);
```

need to be

```
printf("%s %d\n",b,cc);
```

**Other**

You have an unnecessary call to `atoi`. Was that just for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it this way, the algorithm is actually quite simple. Works for every string.

```
char a[] = "abcd123dc2";
char b[20];
char c[20];
int i, spotinnumbers = 0, spotincharacters = 0;
for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(a) ; i++)
{
    if((a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z') || (a[i] >= 'A' && a[i] <= 'Z'))
    {
        b[spotincharacters] = a[i];
        spotincharacters++;
    }
    else if(a[i] >= '0' && a[i] <= '9')
    {
        c[spotinnumbers] = a[i];
        spotinnumbers++;
    }
}
b[spotincharacters] = '\0';
c[spotinnumbers] = '\0';
```

Some explanation of the code. Basically, it's not splitting, just having another two strings, one of the alphabet in the main string and one of the numbers in it. We use one loop to run on the string and decide whether the character is an alphabet letter or a number and assign it in the right place.

About the sum calculation... As we have the numbers in c:

```
int total = 0;
for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(c) ; i++)
{
   total += c[i]-'0';
}
```

explanation about this piece of code, in this code, as a string in C is simply an array of characters, in the string we have the characters resembling the numbers but the characters' value in numeric is something called ASCII value. You can look at the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and find out that each character has a numeric value and there's an overall of 256 characters (2^8) which is why a character takes one byte (1 byte = 8 bits = 2^8 possibilities for different numbers). '0''s ASCII is 48 and that's how we basically turn a number from a character to its true numeric value. for 0 (`48-48` = 0) and for 1 (`49-48 = 1`) as all number characters in the ASCII table are in a series.

The actual problem in the code isn't just efficiency as there is no need to run in two loops and so, you enter the numeric values of the numbers into C ! which turns them to different characters.